# Не сохраняет настройки SharedPrefernces

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Не могу понять почему не сохраняются настройки.

```
public class SharedPreference {

    private final String PREFERENCES = "preferences";

    private Context context;

    public void setContext(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    }

    public SharedPreferences preferences(){
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public Editor editor(){
    return preferences().edit();
    }

    public void write(String key, String value){
        editor().putString(key, value);
        editor().apply();
    }

    public String read(String key){
        return preferences().getString(key, "");
    }
}
```

Ну и вот как вызываю:

```
preference = new SharedPreference();
preference.setContext(getApplicationContext());
preference.preferences();
preference.editor();

preference.write("text", notesList.get(position).getText());
```

Comment: Подозреваю что метод `SharedPreferences.edit()` при каждом вызове возвращает новый экземпляр `Editor` и, соответственно, значение Вы вставили в один, а применяете другой (пустой)

Comment: Для уточнения - вы создали собственный класс ``SharedPreferences`` или пытаетесь использовать стандартный ``SharedPreferences``?

Comment: Балуюсь немного=) Чтобы использовать в различных местах. Как вариант, как можно этот класс переписать?

Comment: Зачем переписывать стандартный класс? Неизвестно потом где какие проблемы могут вылезти. Вон у вас вызывается ``return preferences().edit();``, а ведь метод ``edit()`` у вас отсутствует. Да и ``public SharedPreferences preferences()`` внутри класса  ``SharedPreferences `` странно выглядит (хотя возможно это какие-то особенности явы, с которыми я еще незнаком).

Comment: Вы меня извините за резкость, но вы видимо слабо представляете себе проектирование подобных классов. Вы получаете ненужные объекты, которые "висят" в вакууме, вызываете бесполезные методы и вообще происходит какой то хаос. Вот пример [подобного класса](https://github.com/GrenderG/Prefs) , вы его [изучите](https://github.com/GrenderG/Prefs/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/es/dmoral/prefs/Prefs.java), поймите и напишите свой, а лучше используйте уже готовый

Comment: @Эникейщик это будет клиентский класс, который имеет такое же имя, как и системный, но напрямую к нему не относящийся (будут разные импорты), хотя называть собственные классы одинаковыми именами с системными большая ошибка. Метод `edit()` - метод системного класса, а не клиентского. В общих чертах, код в вопросе - это ад.